# It's all Google in SEDE now

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, google-openid

When logging in with Firefox (no repro on Chrome or IE11) on SEDE the [login page](https://data.stackexchange.com/account/login?returnurl=/) shows only Google icons. I know something had to be fixed due to end of the support of Googles OpenId but this is a little bit to much credit for them.

[image: sede login all google]

Can this be fixed, please?

Comment: Google will rule you all!!

Comment: I kinda like it, you sure this is a problem?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[The SEDE login page](https://data.stackexchange.com/account/login) just got some love, including Firefox fixes:

[image: SEDE login]

The login providers are now SVG which should look much better on high-DPI devices. I'll update the other images to SVGs as soon as time allows. Thanks to our designer [Stéphane ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/245505/st%C3%A9phane-martin) for helping me out on this on very short notice.

Comment: Tim (Stone) is on vacation? :)

Comment: I like this less :( Google all the things!